# unstable wired ethernet network connection after upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04(amd64)

Tags: 14.04, internet, network-manager, ethernet

Recently I upgrade my system from 13.10 to 14.04, after a week I faced unstable wired network connection issue. Checked network manager it shows connection as ok. Below is the detail information of system :

1) Network manager information

nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Auto Ethernet] ------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            tg3
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        00:25:64:C7:5D:87
  Capabilities:
  Carrier Detect:  yes
  Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
  Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
  Address:         172.20.150.51
  Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
  Gateway:         172.20.150.254

  DNS:             172.20.50.4
  DNS:             172.20.50.12

2) Kernel name

uname -r

kernel version : 3.13.11-031311-generic

Network card information : 
command : lspci -vnn | grep -i net
o/p :
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1698] (rev 10)

system information :
Dell optiplex 380 amd-64

Comment: I am facing same issue with my clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 on my new Lenovo L440 laptop. Wifi is not working with driver issue and Ethernet is intermittent. I am clueless on how to proceed! Please let me know if somebody finds some solution